# Wellposedness of SDE with switching diffusion

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Let $b:\mathbb R\to [-1,1]$ and $a_1, a_2:\mathbb R\to [1,2]$ be Lipschitz functions. Consider the stochastic differential equation (SDE) as follows :

$$dX_t = b(X_t)dt + a(X_t)dW_t,$$

where $(W_t)_t$ is a real-valued Brownian motion and

$$a(x):={\bf 1}_{\{b(x)>0\}}a_1(x) + {\bf 1}_{\{b(x)\le 0\}}a_2(x),\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R.$$

Using Krylov's approximation argument, one may deduces the existence of weak solution to this SDE. Under which conditions one may expect the uniqueness (for strong or weak solution)? Or can we construct a counterexample?